# How to use xterm to launch screen with arguments

Tags: unix, gnu-screen, xterm

I'm currently using mobaxterm to launch xterms to connect to a remote server.  I use...

`xterm screen`

I use screen because the connection is unreliable so screen allows me to recover sessions.

What I really want is to call "screen -RR" to reconnect sessions if there, or start a new one, but xterm doesn't allow command line arguments.

I've played around with -e, -ls, -hold, etc but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

[Edit]
Additional information...

I've tried...

`xterm ./script.sh`

with `screen -RR` in it, but that runs, then exits.  `-l` or `-hold` doesn't help.

`xterm -e /bin/bash -c screen -RR`

same problem, exits without giving me a prompt.

My current hack is...
`xterm ./mybash`

where `mybash` a sym-link to `/bin/bash`, and I have a check in `.bashrc` looking for `XTERM_SHELL = mybash`, then launching `screen -RR`, but that runs 2 bash shells, so I have to exit twice to close the window.

Comment: Create an alias and launch external with that?  If alias doesn’t work, create a script and put your command in the script?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I've found tmux to be more powerful than GNU screen. You might consider trying it out. (Nothing wrong with screen if that's what you prefer, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

`xterm -e` should work. It takes one or more arguments specifying a command (plus its arguments) to execute under `xterm` (so it must be the last option).

For example, this should work

```
xterm -e screen -RR
```

There's no need to invoke `/bin/bash` to invoke `screen`.

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  I think I got confused when the other options weren't working and I thought I had flags to say this was a login shell.